# Xcode: glib.h file not found

Tags: c++, xcode, glib, flags, compiler-flags

I've tried to import glib.h to a Xcode C++ project, but I got '*glib.h' file not found* error.

I've tried to add `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` command's output to the *Build Settings* / *Other Linker Flags* (see picture below) but nothing changes.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Encountered same problem. Maybe this can help you out.

I fixed it by adding path of header(inside framework)[image: screenshot attached] in xcode->BuildSettings->HeaderSearchPath